# Is there a way to detect that a css transition has been aborted/interruted?

Tags: javascript, css, transition

According to the [mdn transitionend doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend), the transitionend event of a css transition won't be fired if the transition-property is removed or if the element (or one of its parent of course) becomes display:none.

I was wondering if there would be any way to detect such a case from javascript side (ie.: the transition has been interrupted). As far as i saw, there is no transitioninterrupted event or transitionaborted event, but maybe i missed something ?

Would you have any idea ?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do a little research about it and there really are no other transition events other than `transitionend`, but i found [this pen](http://codepen.io/csuwldcat/pen/EempF) which tried to emulate a `transitionstart` event using a `transitionend` event which triggers after a very short delay.

Basing off that technique, I tried to emulate a `transitioncancel` event and got some "not bad" results. Here is the code for a little demo (explanation comes after):

**HTML**

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

**CSS**

```
h1 {
    margin-left: 0;
    opacity: 0.99999;
    transition: margin-left 1s ease, opacity 0.0001ms ease;
}

h1:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: 500px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var h1 = document.querySelector('h1');
var styles = getComputedStyle(h1);
var duration = resolveDuration(styles.transitionProperty,
    styles.transitionDuration);

var timer = null;
h1.addEventListener('transitionend', function(e) {
    if (e.propertyName === 'opacity') {
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('transition cancelled!');
        }, duration);
    } else {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
});

function resolveDuration(property, duration) {
    var properties = property.split(/,\s+/g);
    var durations = duration.split(/,\s+/g);
    for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
        if (properties[i] !== 'opacity') {
            var unit = durations[i].replace(/\d+\.?\d*/, '');
            var value = parseInt(durations[i].replace(unit, ''));
            if (unit === 's') {
                return value * 1000;
            }
            return value;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Explanation**

- Basically what this does is to start a `setTimeout` call after the emulated `transitionstart`, with the duration set to the `transition-duration` (which is normalized to milliseconds in the `resolveDuration` function).
- When the function passed to `setTimeout` gets executed, it means that the transition got cancelled.
- When another `transitionend` event gets emitted which is not for the `opacity` property (which is used to fake a `transitionstart`), the `setTimeout` call gets cancelled so that fake `transitioncancel` is not emitted.

**Issues with this solution**

- There is a need for another transitioned property (`opacity` in this case) to fake the `transitionstart`.
- Can only handle one transitioned property.
- Fake `transitioncancel` only gets triggered after the `transition-duration`, and not immediately at the point when the transition got cancelled.

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/93m5bzfq/) for a demo of this.